# How to make a separate thread on each row of listview. GC_FOR_ALLOC

Tags: java, android, multithreading, listview

I can't understand how it should be, in my model-class i
am using runnable that counts time and sending it to handler which was initialized in MainActivity. I suppose, what i must using  the Thread class with Handler, but where i must initialize Handler, in adapter? I trying and catch ANR message;

In logcat often write something like this:(even if listview is empty)

```
The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 795K, 56% free 9998K/22280K, paused 11ms, total 12ms
```

Here is the fragment of code of my model:

```
  private String name;
private  Boolean isStart=false, isFinished=false;
private  Long elapsedTime=0L,seconds=0L,hours=0L,minutes=0L,lastPause=0L,updateTime=0L,startTime=0L,days=0L,limitTime=0L;
private Runnable updateTimeThread=new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(isStart && startTime!=0) {
            if(elapsedTime!=0 && updateTime==0)
                lastPause=elapsedTime;
            updateTime = ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + lastPause);
            seconds = updateTime / 1000;
            minutes = seconds / 60;
            hours = minutes / 60;

            seconds = seconds % 60;
            minutes = minutes % 60;
            hours = hours % 24;

            elapsedTime=updateTime;

            holder.days.setText(String.format("%04d", days));
            holder.hours.setText(String.format("%02d", hours));
            holder.minutes.setText(String.format("%02d", minutes));
            holder.seconds.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds));

            if(limitTime!=0 && elapsedTime>limitTime) {
                isFinished = true;
                holder.stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.textFinish.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.limDay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.limMin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.limHours.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.textLimit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                RemindMe.db.execSQL(Util.concat("UPDATE trackers SET isFinish=1, elapsedTime=",limitTime," WHERE _id=",getId()));

            }
            if(!isFinished)
                MainActivity.handler.post(this);

        }
    }
};
MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder;
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder getHolder() {
    return holder;
}
```

Fragment of Adapter

```
  @Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    final Tracker tracker = trackerList.get(position);
    final Runnable updateTimeThread=tracker.getRunnable();
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(row == null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
        holder.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        holder.days = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvDays);
        holder.hours = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvHours);
        holder.minutes = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvMinutes);
        holder.seconds = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvSeconds);
        holder.start = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.btStart);
        holder.stop = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.btStop);
        holder.textFinish = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtFinish);
        holder.textLimit = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtLimit);
        holder.limDay = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.limDay);
        holder.limHours = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.limHours);
        holder.limMin = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.limMin);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    //изнальначальный вид
    final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
    finalHolder.start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    finalHolder.stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    finalHolder.name.setText(tracker.getName());
    if(tracker.getElapsedTime()!=0 && tracker.getLimitTime()==0){//если прошедшее время !=0 и таймер без лимита
        long days = tracker.getElapsedTime()/86400000;
        long hours = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/360000)%24;
        long minutes = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/60000)%60;
        long seconds = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/1000)%60;
        if(days!=0)
            finalHolder.days.setText(Util.concat(days<=9?0:"",days,":"));
        if(hours!=0)
            finalHolder.hours.setText(Util.concat(hours <=9 ?0:"",hours,":"));
        if(minutes!=0)
            finalHolder.minutes.setText(Util.concat(minutes<=9?0:"",minutes,":"));
        if(seconds!=0)
            finalHolder.seconds.setText(Util.concat(seconds<=9?0:"",seconds));
    }
    if(tracker.getIsFinished()){//если таск закончен, дошел до лимита
        long hours = (tracker.getLimitTime()/360000)%24;
        long minutes = (tracker.getLimitTime()/60000)%60;
        long seconds = (tracker.getLimitTime()/1000)%60;
        finalHolder.start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        finalHolder.textFinish.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        finalHolder.stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if(seconds!=60)
            finalHolder.seconds.setText(Util.concat(seconds<=9?0:"",seconds));
        if(minutes!=60)
            finalHolder.minutes.setText(Util.concat(minutes<=9?0:"",minutes,":"));
        if(hours!=24)
            finalHolder.hours.setText(Util.concat(hours <= 9 ? 0 : "", hours, ":"));

    }
    if(tracker.getLimitTime()!=0 && !tracker.getIsFinished()){//если установлен лимит, но еще не дошел до конца
        long days = tracker.getLimitTime()/86400000;
        long hours = (tracker.getLimitTime()/3600000)%24;
        long minutes = (tracker.getLimitTime()/60000)%60;
        finalHolder.textLimit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if(days!=0) {
            finalHolder.limDay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            finalHolder.limDay.setText("" + (days <= 9 ? "0" + days : days) + ":");
        }
        if(hours!=0) {
            finalHolder.limHours.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            finalHolder.limHours.setText(Util.concat(hours <= 9 ? 0 : "", hours, ":"));
        }
        if(minutes!=0) {
            finalHolder.limMin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            finalHolder.limMin.setText(Util.concat(minutes<=9?0:"",minutes,":"));

        }
        if(days==0 && hours==0 & minutes!=0){
            finalHolder.limMin.setText(Util.concat(minutes,"minutes"));
        }
    }

    if(tracker.getIsStart()) {//если был стартован
        finalHolder.start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        finalHolder.stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    onSavedList.set(position,tracker);
    View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btStart:
                    tracker.setStartTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    tracker.setIsStart(true);
                    tracker.setHolder(finalHolder);
                    finalHolder.start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    finalHolder.stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    MainActivity.handler.post(updateTimeThread);
                    break;
                case R.id.btStop:
                    tracker.setLastPause(tracker.getUpdateTime());
                    MainActivity.handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimeThread);
                    finalHolder.stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    finalHolder.start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tracker.setIsStart(false);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    finalHolder.start.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    finalHolder.stop.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    return row;
}
```

And MainActivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>,View.OnClickListener {

    ListView listView;
    MyAdapter adapter;
   static Handler handler;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    List<Tracker> trackerList;

    static final String LOG_TAG = "myTag";
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        handler = new Handler();
        db = RemindMe.db;
        trackerList = Tracker.getListAll(db);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        String[] from = {Tracker.COL_NAME, Tracker.COL_ELAPSED_TIME, Tracker.COL_ELAPSED_TIME, Tracker.COL_ELAPSED_TIME, Tracker.COL_ELAPSED_TIME};
        int[] to = {R.id.tvName, R.id.tvDays, R.id.tvHours, R.id.tvMinutes, R.id.tvSeconds};
        adapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, Tracker.getAll(db), from, to, 0,trackerList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddTrack.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new TrackerLoader(this, db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    }

    static class TrackerLoader extends android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader {
        SQLiteDatabase db;

        TrackerLoader(Context context, SQLiteDatabase db) {
            super(context);
            this.db = db;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            return Tracker.getAll(db);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStop " + hashCode());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onPause "+hashCode());
        for (int i = 0; i <adapter.getCount() ; i++) {
            trackerList.get(i).update(db);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onResume "+hashCode());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy "+hashCode());
    }


}
```

Add task activity:

```
 Tracker tracker;
SQLiteDatabase db;
EditText name,limitHours,limitMinute;
RadioButton limitTime,unlimitTime;
RadioGroup radioGroup;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_track);
    name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
    radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    limitHours = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_Hours);
    limitMinute = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_Min);
    limitTime = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rdbLimit);
    unlimitTime = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rdbUnlimit);
    tracker = new Tracker();
    db = RemindMe.db;//it's db.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

Comment: First of all: clean up your code - it's horrible to read it. Format it correctly and only show the code that is relevant to your problem.
Second: why are you using a `Thread` to change a list item?
Third: add log statements to your code so you can find out what is taking up the time on the UI thread.

Comment: @Darwind
I'am not using  a`Thread`, i'm using a `Runnable` with `Handler`, I want using a `Thread` i think it might solve my problem, Thread will be sending data to handler which has acces to ui. But without items in the listview, i see in logcat: `The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` It happens if i press the button "Add task" with no action and press "Back". During this actions hard work is impossible.

Comment: Well what code is called when you click "Add task" and then press back? What "hard-working" code do you need to execute, since you need a thread? I'm thinking you're doing something wrong, if you need a background thread for filling out list items. Again: clean up your code and show only the code that are actually the issue.

Comment: @Darwind
I don't know where is the issue, "hard-working" code which need to execute it's the count-up timers in every row of listview(let's say 20 items). I read what for this work i must make a separate threads. If the listview have 4 items(four runnable are working) i see "tha application ma be doing..."

Comment: The issue with using threads for this is that multithreading is sometimes "faked", by switching between different work on the same thread, which is what's happening when you use a `Handler` because the `Handler` is basically just a queue that performs tasks on the UI thread. You might be able to use the `Handler` for your code, but I'd recommend trying to use `Handler.postDelayed` instead and put in a small delay - 10 ms for instance and see if that helps. Another solution could be to use an `AsyncTask` instead, because the `AsyncTask` can handle progress and post to the UI thread when needed.

Comment: @Darwind
Yes, i understand how it works)) AsyncTask not useful for long work, it can be used for download files or something else, which will be work only once. And for asynctask you can not set the priority.
Do you think the separate thread on each row is bad solution,using Thread with Handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was very simple, in model class put Thread class which will counts time, sending to Handler some int value, just to turn it on. The handler will change the UI uses the ViewHolder object which will be setted to each item in the listview in getView() adapter's method.

To adapter constructor I send a static List (in getView() method I pull the needed object and work with it), this is very important because, if the list is not static, after the leave Activity with listview and re-entry will be the creation of new instances activity / adapter / models.

Here is the fragment of my model class:
      private String name;

```
private  Boolean isStart=false, isFinished=false;
private Long elapsedTime=0L,seconds=0L,hours=0L,minutes=0L,lastPause=0L,updateTime=0L,startTime=0L,days=0L,limitTime=0L;
class TrackerThread extends Thread{
    public TrackerThread() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        try {
            while (isStart && !isInterrupted()){
            if (isStart && startTime != 0) {
                if (elapsedTime != 0 && updateTime == 0)
                    lastPause = elapsedTime;
                updateTime = ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + lastPause);
                seconds = updateTime / 1000;
                minutes = seconds / 60;
                hours = minutes / 60;

                seconds = seconds % 60;
                minutes = minutes % 60;
                hours = hours % 24;
                elapsedTime = updateTime;
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);//its just for run Handler

                if(limitTime!=0 && elapsedTime > limitTime) {
                    interrupt();
                }else
                    sleep(1000);
            }
            }
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            holder.days.setText(String.format("%04d",days));
            holder.hours.setText(String.format("%02d", hours));
            holder.minutes.setText(String.format("%02d", minutes));
            holder.seconds.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds));

        if(limitTime!=0 && elapsedTime>limitTime) {
            isFinished = true;
            holder.stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.textFinish.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.limDay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.limMin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.limHours.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.textLimit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            RemindMe.db.execSQL(Util.concat("UPDATE trackers SET isFinish=1, elapsedTime=",limitTime," WHERE _id=",getId()));
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Here is the getView() adapter:

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    final Tracker tracker = trackerList.get(position);
    final Thread thread = tracker.getThread();
    ViewHolder holder;
    long days,hours,minutes,seconds;
    long eDays,eHours,eMins,eSecs;

    if(row == null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
        holder.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        holder.days = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvDays);
        holder.hours = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvHours);
        holder.minutes = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvMinutes);
        holder.seconds = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvSeconds);
        holder.start = (ButtonFloatSmall)row.findViewById(R.id.btStart);
        holder.stop = (ButtonFloatSmall)row.findViewById(R.id.btStop);
        holder.textFinish = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtFinish);
        holder.textLimit = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtLimit);
        holder.limDay = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.limDay);
        holder.limHours = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.limHours);
        holder.limMin = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.limMin);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    //изнальначальный вид
    final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
    finalHolder.start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    finalHolder.stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    finalHolder.name.setText(tracker.getName());

    if(tracker.getElapsedTime()!=0 && tracker.getLimitTime()==0){//если прошедшее время !=0 и таймер без лимита
        days = tracker.getElapsedTime()/86400000;
        hours = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/3600000)%24;
        minutes = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/60000)%60;
        seconds = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/1000)%60;
        if(days!=0)
            finalHolder.days.setText(Util.concat(days <= 9 ? 0 : "", days));
        if(hours!=0)
            finalHolder.hours.setText(Util.concat(hours <=9 ?0:"",hours));
        if(minutes!=0)
            finalHolder.minutes.setText(Util.concat(minutes<=9?0:"",minutes));
        if(seconds!=0)
            finalHolder.seconds.setText(Util.concat(seconds<=9?0:"",seconds));
    }
    if(tracker.getIsFinished()){//если таск закончен, дошел до лимита
        hours = (tracker.getLimitTime()/3600000)%24;
        minutes = (tracker.getLimitTime()/60000)%60;
        seconds = (tracker.getLimitTime()/1000)%60;
        finalHolder.start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        finalHolder.textFinish.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        finalHolder.stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if(seconds!=60)
            finalHolder.seconds.setText(Util.concat(seconds<=9?0:"",seconds));
        if(minutes!=60)
            finalHolder.minutes.setText(Util.concat(minutes<=9?0:"",minutes));
        if(hours!=24)
            finalHolder.hours.setText(Util.concat(hours <= 9 ? 0 : "", hours));

    }
    if(tracker.getLimitTime()!=0 && !tracker.getIsFinished()){//если установлен лимит, но еще не дошел до конца
        days = tracker.getLimitTime()/86400000;
        hours = (tracker.getLimitTime()/3600000)%24;
        minutes = (tracker.getLimitTime()/60000)%60;
        finalHolder.textLimit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        finalHolder.limHours.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        finalHolder.limDay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        finalHolder.limMin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        finalHolder.limDay.setText(Util.concat(days <= 9 ? 0 : "", days, ":"));
        finalHolder.limHours.setText(Util.concat(hours <= 9 ? 0 : "", hours, ":"));
        finalHolder.limMin.setText(Util.concat(minutes<=9?0:"",minutes));

        eDays = (tracker.getElapsedTime() / 86400000);
        eHours = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/3600000)%24;
        eMins = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/60000)%60;
        eSecs = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/1000)%60;

        if(eSecs!=0)
            finalHolder.seconds.setText(Util.concat(eSecs<=9?0:"",eSecs));
        if(eMins!=0)
            finalHolder.minutes.setText(Util.concat(minutes<=9?0:"",eMins));
        if(eHours!=0)
            finalHolder.hours.setText(Util.concat(hours<= 9 ? 0 : "", eHours));
        if(eSecs!=0)
            finalHolder.days.setText(Util.concat(days<= 9 ? 0 : "", eDays));


    }else {
        finalHolder.textLimit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        finalHolder.limHours.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        finalHolder.limDay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        finalHolder.limMin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if(tracker.getIsStart() && !tracker.getIsFinished()) {//если был стартован
        finalHolder.start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        finalHolder.stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    tracker.setHolder(finalHolder);
    View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btStart:
                    tracker.setStartTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    tracker.setIsStart(true);
                    tracker.setHolder(finalHolder);
                    finalHolder.start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    finalHolder.stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if(tracker.getUpdateTime()==0)
                        thread.start();
                    else
                        tracker.getThread().start();

                    break;
                case R.id.btStop:
                    tracker.setLastPause(tracker.getUpdateTime());
                    finalHolder.stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    finalHolder.start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tracker.setIsStart(false);
                    break;

            }
        }
    };
    finalHolder.start.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    finalHolder.stop.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    return row;
}
```